# puppet migration: v3.8.5 -> v5.4.0 "Could not find template"

Tags: puppet

I'm migrating a from puppetmaster on Xenial (v3.8.5) to Bionic (v5.4.0) and have run into an issue. So far I've copied the node and modules files from the old server to the new and had a client connect. I keep getting the following error on the client and master:

```
Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 500 on SERVER: Server Error: Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Function Call, Could not find template 'ntp/client_ntp.conf.erb' (file: /etc/puppet/code/environments/production/manifests/modules/ntp/manifests/init.pp, line: 17, column: 20) on node owain18.dimerocker.com
```

The template file exists at: /etc/puppet/code/environments/production/manifests/modules/ntp/templates/client_ntp.conf.erb

The contents of ntp/manifests/init.pp:

```
class ntp {

    package { "ntp": }

    file { "/etc/ntp.conf":
        mode    => "644",
        content => template("ntp/client_ntp.conf.erb"),
        notify  => Service["ntp"],
        require => Package["ntp"],
    } # file

    service { "ntp":
        ensure  => running,
        enable  => true,
        require => Package["ntp"],
    } # service
} # class ntp
```

(I removed some comments from the top of the file so the line number in the error doesn't match, but there's no code missing.)

Any pointers on how to fix this issue? Thanks for your help.

Comment: `/etc/puppet/code/environments/production/manifests/modules` does not seem like a valid Puppet directory environment structure. Try moving the contents of the `manifests/modules` into the proper `modules` directory.

Comment: @Matt Schuchard, yes, that's exactly it. Thanks very much. I'm still getting used to the slightly different file structure and had missed that.